# Catalog of covering maps

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, covering-spaces, online-resources

Is there somewhere where I can find a list of covering maps including their base space and target space? Apart from standard examples found in notes and books I can't find much else.

Comment: Now, I'm not saying that no such thing exists, but what could you possibly need this for?

Comment: (By the way, such a list is unnecessary if you know the space's fundamental group, though perhaps the abstract construction of the covering space corresponding to a subgroup is a bit unsatisfying.)